# how to grouping if data have same attribute value

Tags: reactjs, json

I'm trying to make a portfolio and have a feature to group data if the data has the same attribute value as "group_invoice".

The data I get from the backend is

```js
items: [
{
  customer_code: "DT-18958"
  customer_id: 18958
  invoice_id: "IN-001"
  id: 221
  group_invoice: "GR-1211"
},
{
  customer_code: "DT-18821"
  customer_id: 18958
  invoice_id: "IN-002"
  id: 222
  group_invoice: "GR-1211"
},
{
  customer_code: "DT-18810"
  customer_id: 18953
  invoice_id: "IN-003"
  id: 223
  group_invoice: "GR-1213"
},
{
  customer_code: "DT-18130"
  customer_id: 18953
  invoice_id: "IN-004"
  id: 224
  group_invoice: "GR-1213"
},
{
  customer_code: "DT-18139"
  customer_id: 18955
  invoice_id: "IN-004"
  id: 225
}]
```

What I'm trying to do is, If the data have same `invoice_id` It will grouped and push new array and the new array will look like this. From 5 data above, into 3 data below.

```
item: [
{
  customer_id: 18953
  group_invoice: "GR-1211"
  customer_invoice: [
  {
    customer_code: "DT-18958"
    customer_id: 18958
    invoice_id: "IN-001"
    id: 221
    group_invoice: "GR-1211"
  },
  {
    customer_code: "DT-18821"
    customer_id: 18958
    invoice_id: "IN-002"
    id: 222
    group_invoice: "GR-1211"
  }]
},
{
  customer_id: 18953
  group_invoice: "GR-1213"
  customer_invoice: [
  {
    customer_code: "DT-18958"
    customer_id: 18953
    invoice_id: "IN-001"
    id: 223
    group_invoice: "GR-1213"
  },
  {
    customer_code: "DT-18821"
    customer_id: 18953
    invoice_id: "IN-002"
    id: 224
    group_invoice: "GR-1213"
  }]
},
{
  customer_code: "DT-18139"
  customer_id: 18955
  invoice_id: "IN-004"
  id: 225
}]
```

Can you help me with the logic and functions in React?

Comment: it seems your result has groupd bye `group_invoice` not `invoice_id`

Comment: @SaeedShamloo yes it is, we need to check if the data have `group_invoice` or not

Comment: could you please check my answer.

Answer (score 0):

```js
const items = [ { customer_code: "DT-18958", customer_id: 18958, invoice_id: "IN-001", id: 221, group_invoice: "GR-1211", }, { customer_code: "DT-18821", customer_id: 18958, invoice_id: "IN-002", id: 222, group_invoice: "GR-1211", }, { customer_code: "DT-18810", customer_id: 18953, invoice_id: "IN-003", id: 223, group_invoice: "GR-1213", }, { customer_code: "DT-18130", customer_id: 18953, invoice_id: "IN-004", id: 224, group_invoice: "GR-1213", }, { customer_code: "DT-18139", customer_id: 18955, invoice_id: "IN-004", id: 225, }];

const grouppedItems = items.reduce((acc,obj)=> {
    const {group_invoice:key = 'noGroup'} = obj;
    (acc[key] = acc[key] || []).push(obj)
    return acc;
}, {})

let res = Array.from(Object.entries(grouppedItems), ([key, value]) => {
  return key == 'noGroup' ? value : 
   ({group_invoice: key, customer_id: value[0].customer_id, customer_invoice: value});
}).flat();

console.log(res)
```